# Book indexing with pandoc and crossref for html output?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I realise pandoc and crossref don't currently support anything like the Latex' `makeidx`, but I was wondering if anyone had build on crossref and filters to implement something similar for html or ebook output?

I guess what I really want is the ability to add an attribute to a span which then becomes an item in a list (index) at the end of the book (I'm using bookdown). i.e. this would be an [index item]{.index} I don't personally need anything much more complex (e.g. `seealso` type features).

Any info much appreciated!

Comment: you can always write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html)...

Comment: thanks... I guess I knew this but was hoping someone had already scratched the itch!